How can I find market address and program ID for a new token?
I'm looking into new listed tokens and I'm trying to make an automation that will place orders using Serum, but Serum is asking for Market Address and Program ID.
I cannot figure out a way to find them.
Anyone knows where can I find them for new listed tokens?
// Load the Serum market
const marketAddress = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("..."); // Replace with the Serum market address
const programId = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("..."); // Replace with the Serum program ID

